# deploy Nodes giving problems in Corda

Tags: gradle, corda

This is what I get when I enter ./gradlew deployNodes command. Is this an issue? It has been like this for awhile.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's fine. The Gradle wrapper is downloading the version of Gradle it wishes to use.

This can be slow on a slow internet connection, but should only happen once. Once downloaded, the version of Gradle is stored locally.